# Core Data : In what condition, the thread could not acquire the lock of the NSPersistentStoreCoordinator?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, deadlock

As the below shows, my main thread is waiting the lock, but could not get it all the time.

[image]

[image]

Any condition provided will be much appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are there any other threads locking the store or merging to the main context?

Comment: @DanShelly I don't explicitly lock the store, but the contexts will. And the main context may merge changes from other thread's context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two threads, using the same context, one is reading while the other is writing.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced this when I was trying to delete the persistent store on the main thread while other threads were trying to access data in it.

Comment: Yes, it did. I got a stack trace very similar to yours.